# How do I return a string as if it were printed

Tags: python-3.x

I have a txt file that I get using the requests module.

```
import requests

response = requests.get(url)

str = response.txt
```

If i call str I will get

```
'test\none'
```

as an output(wrong format)

If i return str i get

```
'test/none'
```

as an output(wrong format)

If i print str i get

```
test
one
```

as an output(right format)

how can i get the format of print str without printing it?

I have to use return 
I cannot use print and i cannot use return print

the reason for this is because this is for a flask app so the format has to be

```
@app.route('/')
def home():
    return str
```

or

```
@app.route('/')
def home():
    return render_template('home.html', value=str)
```

Answer (score -1):

Use `repr`, see below:

```
>>> print(repr("your string\n"))
"your string\n"
```